# How can I capture a function result in a lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, capture

I was wondering if I can capture a function result:

```
int main()
{
    struct A { int a; int func() { return a; } };

    A a;

    
    auto lambda = []() {};
    // I WANT THE LAMBDA TO HAVE A COPY OF a.func();
    // In other words I want capture the return value of a.func()


   
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I know that in newer standards of C++ you can create new variables in the capture list, so something like this?

```
auto lambda = [int copy = a.func()] () {   cout << copy; }
```

Comment: ... yes? You can do *precisely* that.  But delete the word `int`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is slightly different. The type of the entity in the capture group is deduced from the initializer, and you can't explicitly specify the type:

```
auto lambda = [copy = a.func()] () { std::cout << copy; };
           // ^ no int
```

You can create multiple entities of different types in the capture group as well, if you just separate them by `,`:

```
auto lambda = [x = a.func(), y = a.func2()] () { std::cout << x << y; };
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tn5695).

Comment: Nice. And for multiple variables? Can you do [a = a.func(), b = a.func2()] () { } ??? I separated it by a comma...

Comment: @Zebrafish yes, you can. See [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) on cppreference.com: "*captures - a **comma-separated list** of zero or more captures, optionally beginning with a capture-default.*"